# update bim360 Revit cloud model using design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I tried to modify properties of bim360 Revit cloud model using design automation (versionType: 'versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel'), got below error:

```
{id: 'ce58ade7-b556-4817-9ea9-f2180346ddac', status: '400', code: 'BAD_INPUT', title: 'Object violates schema "versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel-1.0".', detail: 'See meta section for details.'}
```

is it still due to restriction of Revit CM and/or CWM?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, users cannot create `versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel` type. You must use Revit Cloud Model API to open and sync changes to the central model instead.

- [Application#OpenDocumentFile Method (ModelPath, OpenOptions, IOpenFromCloudCallback)](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/dcdca59a-635c-a6ca-8378-b1e6bb372101.htm)
- [Document#SynchronizeWithCentral](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/7de73a7b-68f0-87f2-f6a9-97d824024877.htm)

However, due to the restriction of Revit CM and/or CWM, you cannot currently use Revit Cloud Model API on DA. Our engineering is still working on it. Please stay tuned with us. But you still can achieve this with Revit Desktop. Here is a sample using the above API: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcw.file.migration-revit.addon

Comment: thanks Eason, if i understand correctly, current workaround will be -> download from bim360/acc, change properties, upload to bim360/acc, correct? can all those 3 steps be done automatically via DA?

Comment: No, you need to open the Cloud Worksharing model with Revit desktop by UI or using Revit Cloud Model API, change properties, and sync the change by clicking the `Synchronize with Central` on the UI or using the Revit API mentioned above to upload the changes to  BIM360/ACC, and then publish cloud model by UI or call [Forge API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/PublishModel/). Currently, you cannot do this on DA, since you cannot create `versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel`.

Comment: Here is the [workflow of RCW on UI](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-Cloud/files/GUID-ABFFFEE6-2C6D-4779-B508-A1C4BC0C4885-htm.html) for your reference.

Comment: got it, thanks Eason and have a great weekend!